# The type or namespace name 'GCCheckbox' could not be found

Tags: checkbox, xamarin.forms

i am trying to create checkbox control using custom renderer for my xamarin.forms application.

i refereed this [Link](https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/using-a-custom-native-control-with-xamarin-forms-via-a-custom-renderer/)

but for ios custom renderer it can not find

> GCCheckbox.Checkbox ;

and i am geeting this error.

so which namespace or dll i am missing here.please suggest.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article:

> **Since iOS does not have a native checkbox control, we created one of
>   our own previously**. This means we'll need to add our Xamarin.iOS
>   project into this solution and add it as a reference to the iOS
>   portion of our CustomRenderer Project.

As you see `GCCheckbox.Checkbox` is a [custom control](http://www.goxuni.com/671974-creating-a-xamarin-bindings-library-for-a-custom-ios-control/) created by the author.

Asking questions does not cost anything, however, if you follow an article or a blog post pay attention to the details. It will reduce the amount of time you spend on the implementation and save a time for the stackoverflow community members.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you. i don not understand how they created custom control.is there any other way to use checkbox using any third party control ?

Comment: Take a look on XLabs: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Checkbox-Control it is open sourced. So you will get an idea. Otherwise the article you checked should work as well. Re-read it again.